# Appending categories to existing items?

Tags: magento, magmi

I needed to add categories to existing products but when I did that using the **"On the fly category creator/importer v0.2.5"** it reset existing categories with categories I tried to append.

I know I can export products via Dataflow Profiles and then append new category ID's to existing ID's but I'd rather not when I have to update many products with different attributes and also have to check so many category ID's. Is there a feature to prevent category reset?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Known issue that was resolved by Dweeves by adding an optional column field:
`category_reset` 
Set to 0 to keep existing categories intact.